# Powershell execute sql queries using sqlplus

Tags: oracle, powershell

I have a RHEL server with Oracle 10G installed. I need to write a powershell script to query my database and get the output. I have imported Posh-SSH module and am able to connect to my RHEL server and execute commands using Invoke-SSHCommand however, i need help in executing sqlplus command using my Invoke-SSHCommand. Normally, we can achieve this in perl using EOF but, am not able to find any way to get this done using powershell.

**code for Perl using EOF:**

```
$command="export ORACLE_SID=DB10G
sqlplus -S santhosh/password@DB10G << EOF
set feedback off
select username from dba_users;
EOF"
```

**My Powershell code:**

```
    $command="export ORACLE_SID=DB10G
    sqlplus -S santhosh/password@DB10G << EOF
    set feedback off
    select username from dba_users;
    EOF"

    $result = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command $command
    Write-Output $result
```

**My Output for Powershell:**

```
Host       : XX.XX.XXX.XXX
Output     : 
ExitStatus : 127
```

I guess, EOF characters are understood by Powershell.

Can anyone help me in converting this to powershell?. I tried many ways but all in vain. Everytime i execute this code, i get Exit code: 127.

Thanks,
Santhosh

---

Yes, i am able to execute other shell commands.

**For Example:**

```
$result = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "whoami"
write-Output $result.Output
```

**My Output:**

```
oracle
```

If i copy the sqlplus command and paste it in a shell prompt, i'm getting the output.

Quite confused with what exactly is happening.

---

When i execute other commands (**like "cat"**) with EOF, it executes fine.

```
$cmd="cat > hello.txt << EOF
This is 1st line
This is 2nd line"
$result = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command $cmd
write-Output $result
```

The file is created in my linux machine.

```
[oracle@oracleDB ~]$ cat hello.txt
This is 1st line
This is 2nd line
```

If i add the ending "EOF" to the above command, somehow my shell prompt is treating it as another input to my cat command and adds the line to the file.

```
$cmd="cat > hello.txt << EOF
This is 1st line
This is 2nd line
EOF"
$result = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command $cmd
write-Output $result
```

It turns out like this:

```
[oracle@oracleDB ~]$ cat hello.txt
This is 1st line
This is 2nd line
EOF
```

Can any one explain me what is happening here?.

Thanks,
Santhosh

Comment: Your issue is not so much with PowerShell as it is with `Invoke-SshCommand`. PowerShell doesn't attempt to do anything with the string you're passing, and the "<<EOF" syntax should be processed by the remote shell. What's the result of a simpler command (like "echo hello")?

Comment: PowerShell does do *something* with the string you're passing -- if your password contains a dollar sign, make sure to escape this using a backtick or PowerShell will interpret it as a variable replacement.

Comment: It might be something to do with the fact that you're executing two commands -- `export` and `sqlplus`. Does "whoami ; whoami" work? How about if you split *those* with newlines?

Comment: Yes, I can execute multiple commands in my shell using ";". Only this is causing problem. In this SQLPLUS scenario, if i use ":" in between my commands then it will be considered as a shell command by my linux prompt and it will try to execute every line separately and it will throw a lot of other errors.